# How to loop through API call data and display in view

Tags: swiftui

I know I can use for each for this, but every time I try to implement according to documentation it throws some kind of error regarding syntax.

Here is my view:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct HomeTab: View {

    @StateObject var callDevices = CallDevices()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            devices
           .onAppear {
               callDevices.getDevices()
           }
        }

    }
    
    
    private var devices: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: nil) {
            ForEach(content: callDevices.getDevices(), id: \.self) { device in
             // i want to loop through and display here //
               HStack{
                   Text(device.Name)
                   Text(device.Status)
               }
            }
            Spacer()
        }
     }  

}

struct HomeTab_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HomeTab()
    }
}
```

Here is my Call Devices which works without issue in other views:

```
class CallDevices: ObservableObject {
private var project_id: String = "r32fddsf"

@Published var devices = [Device]()

func getDevices() {
    guard let url = URL(string: "www.example.com") else {return}
    
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("Authorization")
    
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        guard error == nil else {print(error!.localizedDescription); return }
        // guard let data = data else {print("empty data"); return }

        let theData = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Welcome.self, from: data!)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.devices = theData.devices
        }
        
    }
    .resume()
}

}
```

is the issue in the way I am calling my function?

Comment: At the very least, you're missing a `)` after `id: \.self`. Beyond that, it's hard today because some of your code isn't included so it's tough to say if, for example, `device` has properties named `Name` and `Status`.

Comment: @jnpdx that was just a typo, apologies. `device` does have those properties, the problem I'm having is just getting the syntax correct for the `ForEach`, the error I get is `Type of expression is ambigious without more context` on the VStack.

Comment: Can you include enough code for an [mre]?

Comment: Where does a guy named 'CallDevices' come from?

Comment: Hi I have updated my question

Comment: show the code for `CallDevices`, and remove `content:` in the `ForEach`.

Comment: @workingdog done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:
(you may need to make `Device` Hashable)

```
private var devices: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: nil) {
        ForEach(callDevices.devices, id: \.self) { device in  // <-- here
         // i want to loop through and display here //
           HStack{
               Text(device.Name)
               Text(device.Status)
           }
        }
        Spacer()
    }
 }
```

If `Device` is `Identifiable`, you can remove the `id: \.self`.

```
struct Device: Identifiable, Hashable, Codable {
    let id = UUID()
    var Name = ""
    var Status = ""
    // ... any other stuff you have
}
```

Comment: How do I make it hashable?

Comment: like this: `struct Device: Hashable {
    var Name = ""
    var Status = ""
}` but it is best to make it Identifiable, like this: `struct Device: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
    var Name = ""
    var Status = ""
}`